# Beveling the edge ruins the shading

Tags: modeling, mesh, shaders, topology, bevel

I'm trying to model a pistol and I'm currently working on the frame. I tried to bevel the sharp edges of the grip in order to make it smoother as it is also necessary for some details but turns out that after I applied the bevel the way I wanted the shading on the grip got ruined.

Even though the surface beside it is completely flat but I still get a bad shading on the mesh.

Also everything is in quads there are no n-gons or triangles on the mesh.

The steps I've taken but didn't help:

1. Recalculated the Normals
2. Reset the Vectors
3. Cleared the Custom Split Normals from Geometry Data
4. Applied *Weighted Normal* modifier

How can I fix this bad shading?

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot]

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what is supposed to be sharp and what is supposed to be round, do you have a reference image?

Comment: Hey moonboots, thank you for your reply, I don't really have a specific reference I'm using multiple pistols as a reference to come up with something new, I just want the part that will generally be held by hand to be smooth. I marked the sharp edges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would avoid any *Mark Sharp* and instead use this kind of topology (2 different bevels, one narrow where you want the edge to be sharp, one larger when you want the edge to be round):

[image]

If you want to use *Mark Sharp*, select all, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> > *Reset Vectors* then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Clear Sharp*, then *Mark Sharp* again on the edges you want, and give your object a *WeightedNormal* modifier, enable its *Keep Sharp* option. It will smooth the faces except the big ones:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your clear clarification. My problem is solved and most importantly I learned a new approach.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to BSE,

Additional to the advice provided by moonbots, I think you may have an issue with a pole vertex that is connected to **five** edges instead of **four**:

[image]

[image]

I am by no means an expert when it comes to perfect topology, but I believe 5-edge pole verts like this one can lead to shading errors.

Comment: Hello, SlickRed, thank you for your advice, I didn't know about that, but I'll keep that in mind. Your answer is greatly appreciated.